# Deep copy linked list with arbitrary nodes

Tags: c#, linked-list, interview-questions

The original question can be found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-linked-list-with-next-and-arbit-pointer/).

I implemented method 2:

Please comment about style, unit testing, code complexity, time and memory space and complexity.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class LinkedListArbitraryPointer
    {
        public ArbNode Root { get; set; }           

        public ArbNode DeepCopyLinkedList(ArbNode root)
        {
            if(root ==null)
            {
              return null;
            }

            //1) Create the copy of node 1 and insert it between node 1 & node 2 in original Linked List, create the copy of 2 and insert it between 2 & 3.. 
            //Continue in this fashion, add the copy of N afte the Nth node
            ArbNode temp = root;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                ArbNode swap = temp.Next;
                temp.Next = new ArbNode(temp.Index);
                temp.Next.Next = swap;
                temp = temp.Next.Next;
            }

            // 2) Now copy the arbitrary link in this fashion  
            //  original->next->arbitrary = original->arbitrary->next;  /*TRAVERSE TWO NODES*/

            temp = root;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                temp.Next.Arb = temp.Arb.Next;
                temp = temp.Next.Next;
            }

            //3) Now restore the original and copy linked lists in this fashion in a single loop.
            temp = root;
            ArbNode current = root.Next;
            ArbNode storeList = root.Next;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                temp.Next = temp.Next.Next;
                if (current.Next != null)
                {
                    current.Next = current.Next.Next;
                }
                temp = temp.Next;
                current = current.Next;
            }

            return storeList;
        }

    }

    public class ArbNode
    {
        public ArbNode(int index)
        {
            Index = index;
            Next = null;
            Arb = null;
        }

        public ArbNode()
        {
            Next = null;
            Arb = null;
        }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public ArbNode Next { get; set; }
        public ArbNode Arb { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using ConsoleApplication2;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class LinkedListArbPointerUnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            LinkedListArbitraryPointer list = new LinkedListArbitraryPointer();

            list.Root = new ArbNode(1);

            list.Root.Next = new ArbNode(2);

            //2->1
            list.Root.Next.Arb = list.Root;

            list.Root.Next.Next = new ArbNode(3);

            //1 -> 3
            list.Root.Arb = list.Root.Next.Next;

            list.Root.Next.Next.Next = new ArbNode(4);

            //4->3
            list.Root.Next.Next.Next.Arb = list.Root.Next.Next;

            list.Root.Next.Next.Next.Next = new ArbNode(5);

            //5->2
            list.Root.Next.Next.Next.Next.Arb = list.Root.Next;

            //3->5
            list.Root.Next.Next.Arb = list.Root.Next.Next.Next.Next;
            //var res = list.DeepCopyLinkedListWithAuxArray(list.Root);
            var res = list.DeepCopyLinkedList(list.Root);
            Assert.AreEqual(1,res.Index);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, res.Arb.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Var**

Use the `var` keyword when defining local variables where the right hand side of the definition makes the type obvious. This looks cleaner and saves time when it comes to changing types during refactoring.

e.g.

```
LinkedListArbitraryPointer list = new LinkedListArbitraryPointer();
```

should be

```
var list = new LinkedListArbitraryPointer();
```

You actually do use `var` at points, but not consistently.

**Naming**

Avoid using shortened names for your variables, at a glance `res` is not entirely clear what it refers to, prefer `actual` or `deepCopiedList` instead. The same goes for `ArbNode`.

**Definitely** don't name your test methods `TestMethodX`! Find a naming style you like that's concise, detailed and consistent and *stick with it*.

**Comments**

Your comments seem to describe *what* you're doing (which is the job of your code) and not *why* you are doing it. I often find if there is some chunk of code that needs a comment explaining what it does, it can often be refactored to its own method, or made clearer somehow.

**Design**

The property 'Root' seems entirely out of place and unused by your code, remove it.

Additionally, I would consider making `ArbNode` implement `IEnumerable` so you can replace all your:

```
        ArbNode temp = root;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            ...
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
```

with a cleaner:

```
foreach(var node in root)
{
    ...
}
```